# Unity RPG dialogue

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

i'm trying to make a dialogue script for a rpg game.

this is my code for now.

```
#pragma strict

var keyNext : KeyCode;
var text = new Array();
var page = 0;

function OnCollisionEnter2D(col : Collision2D) {
    Debug.Log ("COLLISION DETECTED");
    if(col.gameObject.name == "NPC") {
        text[0] = "hi";
    text[1] = "bye";
} else {
    Debug.Log("no text for "+col.gameObject.name);
}
Debug.Log(text.length);
if(Input.GetKey(keyNext) && text.length < page) {
    page++;
}
Debug.Log(text[page]);
}

function OnCollisionExit2D(col : Collision2D) {
page = 0;
Debug.Log("walked away");
}

function update () {

}
```

but it only prints 'hi', doesn't go to 'bye' when i press the keyNext key (spacebar)

i hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking Input.GetKey in OnCollisionEnter2D. Try to move it to Update-function instead, like this: https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html

In addition you might want to consider using GetKeyUp instead of GetKey; https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyUp.html